# SQL Self Subquery Improvement

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a table `ENCOUNTERS` in an Oracle 11g database, sample healthcare data,

```
ID  DC_DATE CPI
1   "1/1/2012"  a
2   "1/2/2012"  b
3   "1/3/2012"  c
4   "1/4/2012"  d
5   "2/2/2012"  a
6   "2/1/2012"  b
7   "2/3/2012"  e
8   "2/4/2012"  f
9   "2/5/2012"  g
10  "2/29/2012" a
```

ID is a unique visit identifier for a person and CPI is a Person ID that tracks when people come visit us again at later dates.

I have been tasked with creating a query that returns all those columns plus the three new columns, `PREVIOUS_ID, PREVIOUS_DC_DATE, and READMIT_DAYS` Readmit_Days is the difference in days between the new visits DC_Date and their previous visits DC_Date.

Currently I have to run the following code to get the data I need.

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.DC_DATE, 
       a.CPI, 
       (SELECT MAX(b.ID) 
        FROM   ENCOUNTERS b 
        WHERE  a.CPI = b.CPI 
               AND a.ID > b.ID)                             AS Previous_ID, 
       (SELECT MAX(b.DC_DATE) 
        FROM   ENCOUNTERS b 
        WHERE  a.CPI = b.CPI 
               AND a.DC_DATE > b.DC_DATE)                   AS Previous_DC_Date, 
       ( a.DC_DATE - ((SELECT MAX(b.DC_DATE) 
                       FROM   ENCOUNTERS b 
                       WHERE  a.CPI = b.CPI 
                              AND a.DC_DATE > b.DC_DATE)) ) AS ReAdmit_Days 
FROM   ENCOUNTERS a;
```

Now this works, but it just looks way too complicated to me. Is there a better way to get what I need?

This is what I get when it runs, which is correct. Just looking for suggestions.

```
ID  DC_DATE CPI Previous_ID Previous_DC_Date    Readmit_Days
1   "1/1/2012"  a           
2   "1/2/2012"  b           
3   "1/3/2012"  c           
4   "1/4/2012"  d           
5   "2/2/2012"  a   1   "1/1/2012"  32
6   "2/1/2012"  b   2   "1/2/2012"  30
7   "2/3/2012"  e           
8   "2/4/2012"  f           
9   "2/5/2012"  g           
10  "2/29/2012" a   5   "2/2/2012"  27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    with encounters as (
select 1 id, to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') dc_date,  'a' cpi from dual union all
select 2, to_date('01/02/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'b' from dual union all
select 3, to_date('01/03/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'c' from dual union all
select 4, to_date('01/04/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'd' from dual union all
select 5, to_date('02/02/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'a' from dual union all
select 6, to_date('02/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'b' from dual union all
select 7, to_date('02/03/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'e' from dual union all
select 8, to_date('02/04/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'f' from dual union all
select 9, to_date('02/05/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  'g' from dual union all
select 10, to_date('02/29/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'a' from dual)
select id, dc_date, cpi, previous_id, previous_dc_date, dc_date - previous_dc_date readmit_days
from 
(select id, dc_date, cpi, 
        max(id) over (partition by cpi order by id range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as previous_id,
        max(dc_date) over (partition by cpi order by dc_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as previous_dc_date
  from encounters);
```

Analytic functions are better here. In your query you make a lot of extra correlated queries.

P.S. The second window (which uses dc_date and "rows" windowing) won't work correctly with ties. You may use "range" and intervals here. It's just an example.

Comment: Very interesting. I will look into the keywords you use. I have never used over and partition by. I am still trying to wrap my head around how this works. Thanks